# Read SqlDataReader after Exception -- LIKE SSMS Result Pane

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssms, sqlcommand

Is there a way to get the `Reader` object from `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader` without failing on `SqlException`?

In SSMS, for this command:

```
RAISERROR (15600, 12, 5, 'example');
SELECT   * FROM TableName
```

I got error info + Result pane of `TableName`.

When I am excuting `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader`  with this command, I am getting an `SqlException`, but I can't get the result data.
is there a way to skip the exception , and handling the `Reader` object?

Comment: ExecuteAsReader? Where did you find this method?

Comment: You can swap: first, do the select and next raise an error - it should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid throwing a `SqlException` and continue executing the batch after errors, you can set the connection [`FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.fireinfomessageeventonusererrors) property to true and handle the connection [`InfoMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage) event. The `Infomessage` handler will be then be invoked instead of throwing a `SqlException` and you can continue processing `SqlDataReader` results using `Read` and `NextResult`.